# building an ordered list from small to big

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have the following hardcoded JSON:

```
 var myData = [
                  {"Identifier":1,"Naam":"Van Der Valk","Adres":"Europaweg 218","Postcode":"1238AC","Plaats":"Zoetermeer","Longitude":"4.48822","Latitude":"52.06258", "Status":"Laadpunten Beschikbaar", "lunch":"true", "diner":"true", "meet":"true", "wifi":"true"},
                  {"Identifier":2,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Rotterdam","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000", "lunch":"false"},
                  {"Identifier":3,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 6","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Rotterdam","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000", "lunch":"false"},
                  {"Identifier":4,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Den Haag","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000", "lunch":"false"},
                  {"Identifier":5,"Naam":"plek b met lunch en diner","Adres":"NOT Given 218","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Zoetermeer","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000", "lunch":"true", "diner":"true", "wifi":"true"}
                  ];
```

This json i use in my ios phonegap app.. Each line of code in the Json is a point in the netherlands.. I am trying to build a function which calculates the distance between where the phone is and the lat and long from the json.. eventually these json code needs to come in a ordered list where also the distance are from small to big..

for the distance measurement i Used this:

```
 function haversine() {
            $.each(myData, function(index, element) {
                   var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km

                   var dLat  = rad(element.Latitude - lat1);


                   var dLong = rad(element.Longitude - long1);

                   var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                   Math.cos(rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(rad(element.Latitude)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
                   var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
                   var d = R * c;

                   //var element = document.getElementById('afstand');
                   //element.innerHTML = 'afstand: ' + d.toFixed(3);

                   $('.greenfluxlist').append('<li id="' + element.Identifier + '"><a href="Details.html?id=' + element.Identifier + '" rel="external">' + element.Naam + ' ' + element.Plaats +  '<p> <br/>' + element.Adres + ',<br/> ' + element.Postcode + ' ' + element.Plaats + '<br/> Status: ' + element.Status +  '</p> <span class="ui-li-count">' + d.toFixed(3) + '</span></a></li>');
                   });

            $('.greenfluxlist').trigger('create'); 
            $('.greenfluxlist').listview('refresh');

            //return d.toFixed(3);

        }
```

What my problem now is, how can i build the ordered list, is it possible to get everything into an array and then loop through it or something else, i think there has to be a simple solution but i don't know.

Comment: With "ordered list" you mean an html OL? Do you need it to be in a specific order?

Comment: yes for example if the first json code with identifier 1 has 20 km and the 2nd identifier 10 km then the info with the second identifier needs to be on top of the <ul> list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort an array, use the *sort* method.

You should calculate the distance first, then sort the array, and then generate the list. Something like this:

```
function calculateDistance(element)
{
    var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km

    var dLat  = rad(element.Latitude - lat1);
    var dLong = rad(element.Longitude - long1);

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(rad(element.Latitude)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    return R * c;
}

function generateList(data)
{
    for(var i=0; i<data.lenght; i++)
    {
        var element = data[i];
        //var element = document.getElementById('afstand');
        //element.innerHTML = 'afstand: ' + element.Distance.toFixed(3);

        $('.greenfluxlist').append('<li id="' + element.Identifier + '"><a href="Details.html?id=' + element.Identifier + '" rel="external">' + element.Naam + ' ' + element.Plaats +  '<p> <br/>' + element.Adres + ',<br/> ' + element.Postcode + ' ' + element.Plaats + '<br/> Status: ' + element.Status +  '</p> <span class="ui-li-count">' + element.Distance.toFixed(3) + '</span></a></li>');
    }
}

for(var i=0; i<myData.length; i++)
{
    myData[i].Distance = calculateDistance(myData[i]);
}

myData.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.Distance > b.Distance;
});

generateList(myData);
```

Comment: this is not what i need i think.

Comment: Why not? Maybe I din't understand the problem, but I think it is what you need. Do you need any clarification on what the code does?